# HTML5 & CSS media attributes media queries question

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I was wondering what does the operators `and`, `only`, `not` and the comma `,` do and mean when used with the media queries?

Are there any other operators that can be used with the media queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [Media Queries Specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries/), it's only 1 page long. In summary though:

- `and` means both things must match
- `,` means one of the things must match
- `not` means the query is true when it doesn't match
- `only` is mentioned in the spec but I can't find a definition. I suspect it does nothing.

Comment: are these the only operators for media queries?

Comment: no, there's `min-` and `max-` variations on some keywords as well.  `all` is a reserved word as well (meaning all media types). Your answers are in the linked specification.